# confluent differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a similar problem and I would appreciate any help in this matter. The DE that I am dealing with is:

$$z(z-1)f_{zz} + (az-1)f_z+ (b+cz)f=0$$

where $a, b, c$ are constant and $f_z$ is the first derivative of $f(z)$ and $f_{zz}$ is the second derivative.

I believe that this eq. must be related to the confleunt differential equation, but for some reasons I cannot find this form in the books. Can anyone give a reference books where I can find this equation and its solution? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$z(z-1)f_{zz} + (az-1)f_z+ (b+cz)f=0$$
On the basic forms, the confluent hypergeometric and the hypergeometric differential equation have constant coefficient for the $f(x)$ term :

Confluent : $zf''+(c-x)f'-af=0$

hypergeometric : $z(1-z)f''+(c-(a+b+1)z)f'-abf=0$

The coefficient $(b+cz)$ complicates a lot the problem. This might be related to some Meijer-G functions (I don't confirm this). I am not surprized that you cannot find this ODE in the usual books.

I am afraid that you will have to use numerical methods of solving.

Answer (score 0):

In fact this relates to [Heun's Confluent Equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/31.12#E1).